# Passing variables from one included Ansible playbook to another

Tags: ansible

Let's say I wanted some variables passed from the command-line to a playbook, and then to another (included) playbook, what is the cleanest way to go about this ?

I guess I'd go like this ?

`[me@my_box]$ ansible-playbook -i foo -e "server_farm=qa2" playbooks/main_pb.yaml`

Now, let's say that in my main playbook I wanted to pass the server_farm variable to an included included playbook, I'd go like this ?

```
---
# playbook: main_pb.yaml

[some stuff]
tasks:
  - include subtasks/init_services.yaml {{ server_farm }}
```

And how about using this variable in init_services.yaml ? Would I go like:

```
---
# playbook: init_services.yaml

[some stuff]
- name: start some_service
  [some start service stuff]
  when: server_farm == "qa2"
```

Did I get this right ? If so, is it the cleanest way to go about it ?

--Jeff
(as you might have guessed, I'm on my first legs with Ansible; lots of potential in there)

Answer (score 1):

Got my answer while re-reading Ansible doc:

Since my initial variables are passed at the command line (-e parameter), those variables are global in scope and thus don't need to be passed from playbook to playbook.